# I am building a homemade RPG and i want to implement a completely freeform magic system

Tags: spells, magic, house-rules, wizard, freeform

I have decided to venture into building a completely tweakable magic system based on a new set of game mechanics entirely of my own making.
The system is skill-based (As opposed to stat-based, if you know DnD you know what i'm talking about). Magic is a innate skill and has no material compoments, but has always somatic and sometimes verbal ones. It is based on weaving the "Wyrd", an ethereal warp that surrounds and permeates the game's reality and that only people with the gift (mages) can see and touch. Magic is currently subdivided into 6 "skills" or magic schools/talents: 
- Elemental (fire-water-air-earth)
- Mind/Illusion/Dream/Chrme
- Blood Magic and Necromancy (sacrifice-based magic and reviving the undead)
- Nature Magic (life, plants, animal, druidic stuff in DnD)
- Enchantment (enchanting objects, potions, scrolls, and everything really)
- Divination (knowing the future, the past, and seeing in other places)
My idea is that i want mages in the game to be able to be able to pull off anything that they can come of and within the limit of their magic abilities. Magic when mishandled will be deadly for mages but they can try anything they want to, their life is always at stake.
There are for each "school" 7 skill levels that can be attained. The higher the level the more powerful the mage.

I would like to build a system based on quick flowcharts to calculate the mana required for their spell. This should be easy to calculate as is done in game and should not slow the party down too much. Ideally a mage character has a fowchart table that allows him/her to quickly tell the DM "I want to cast a spell that does :..... and the mana cost should be ....., is it ok?"
He then rolls the appropriate dice which determine how well he performs and how much mana/lifeforce the spell drains from him/her.

The thing is: does any such system already exist? I would love to have the flowchart multipliers already worked out. The mana cost of a spell should vary from 5 (trivial, like simple tricks) to 100 (divine skill).

Thanks in advance for the help
Andrea

Comment: Well, I  have one question out of curiosity, do you want to calculate the mana efficiency due to the effect of the spell or the complexity of it, (or both)? for example, healing damage: one might try to use time-space magic to revert the affected area to a previous state, other would try to use the natural healing process of the body. The effect at the end would be the "same", but the complexity and mana consuption not necessarily.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all trying to help. To curiosity i would definitely restrict healing to natural school spells. Bringing time back would be too complex to limit to the wound area. Ideally to keep things simple one could just stick to effect level, but of course it means what is considered complexity. My idea was to devise a set of multipliers depending on -distance; - force; -timing (non-immediate spells being more expensive); -duration; -ability to cast in peace or affected by time, noise or movement constaints... and the like

Comment: To all above people who have commented with partial answers or 'this isn't an answer but...'. These **will** get deleted. If you have an answers, please post them as answers.

Comment: @Wibbs please educate me, as one of the "offenders".  If someone says "I want to know how much hobbits weigh", and I don't know how much hobbits weigh, but I tell them they might be able to find it in the Monster Manual, which I don't own and so I can't give them the answer they seek, how is that not a valid comment to tell them where to look?

Comment: Actually that's a bit of a shame, some of those comments were helpful @Wibbs

Comment: Because its an answer masquerading a comment. This is a bad thing, because comments sidestep a large amount of the quality control that answers are subject to, including voting down and the ability of other site users to edit them. It is established site policy for moderators to delete comments that contain part or complete answers, particularly for questions that are or are going to be closed. I was just warning users who had posted these types of comments that this was going to happen **shrug**

Comment: @AndreaCampisano I'm the one that flagged them for deletion. (Though Wibbs might have, also, I suppose.) My reasons are exactly as Wibbs describes above. Comments are for requesting clarification or improving the post to which they're attached, answers are for answers. Comments are not a shortcut to providing a small (worse, incomplete!) answer that "jumps the line" of the Stack software. (I don't remember your comment specifically, so I'm not trying to characterize *it* there--just my *general* feelings on comment-in-answer being a problem.)

Comment: @Paul in that case you have a few options. (a) Answer the question exactly as you described. It probably won't get considered a good answer (since it lacks the reference you explicitly say is needed), but you've gotten the information to the querent. (b) Bookmark the question and come back to it when you do have the reference available. (c) Don't do anything, and trust that one of the thousands of other citizens will be able to provide querent a high-quality answer.

Comment: Hello again and thanks to Wibbs and nistua60 for their detailed answers.
I am not sure i understand all the details of why this is a bad thing, but i will acknowledge my ignorance on the subject by simply accepting you decisions. I'm new here and so this may sound as such a newbie question, but i see this flagged as offtopic. Is this the case? If so, is it offtopic in all the forum or i just picked th wrong subforum?
Andrea

Answer (score 5):

[Ars Magica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars_Magica) is probably the most famous *free-form* magic system, from which others have been made following a similar formula.

Basically, the spellcasting system is based on 15 *Arts*, which are divided between 5 *Techniques* (create, destroy, transform, etc) and 10 *Forms* (fire, water, plants, animals, etc). The combination of a technique and a form will create the magical effect, which follows a table so the GM and player can know the limit of the spell effect created.

[Shadows of Esteren](https://www.esteren.org/shadows_of_esteren/) is another system where spellcasters are free to do whatever they want with their powers as long as the *spellcasting table* is respected. The system has a single skill for spellcasting for each *tradition* (basically, arcane, divine and druidic) and their limitations are very similar to each other.

The power of the magical effect and what it's limit will be depends on how much energy you put into it and if you can beat the difficult class with a skill check using the proper spellcasting skill.

[Trevas RPG](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trevas) is a brazillian game system and setting that borrowed from both [Call of Cthulhu RPG by Chaosium](http://www.chaosium.com/call-of-cthulhu-rpg/) and *Ars Magica*. It has both a d% dice system for skill rolls and a magic system very similar to Ars Magica's.

Basically, you have 3 form atributes (create, change and destroy) and a variety of "arts" (fire, water, light, shadow, plants, humans, spirits, etc), and by combining their effects you will create the spell. Each of those form atributes have a limitation on a *spellcasting table* aswell, and the arts have a generic limitation that works the same for all of them. Then, the book describes what to expect from each rank on those arts, instead of focusing on specific spell effects. The spell system also features rituals, which can be learned and requires a certain ranks on one or two combination of form and art to work.

Sadly, it's only in portuguese, but it is worth mentioning.

[Mage, The Ascension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mage%3A_The_Ascension) has a spell system similar to Ars Magica's aswell, but it is a bit more restricted on what you can do, but still favors the creative players. The character has ranks on *spheres*, which are basically magical skills available only to mages, and depending on his rank, the amount of things and the limit of his powers will change.

I would say that, if you want to create a free magic system, it's worth to take a look on both **Ars Magica** and **Mage, the Ascension** for ideas. As you can see, Ars's Magica spawned a lot of ideas and new magic systems, so it will be mentioned everytime someone asks for a spell system that is *free* or "*different from D&D's*"

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. It appears i have a lot of reading to do, and probably a lot of adapting too (including testing my Poruguese skills). Too bad but good to have some help here. I'll come back and ask again when at the next stage, possibly on this same thread so to avoid double-posting. P.S.: if someone's interested in this set of rules and wants to try, i'd be happy to oblige, although it's currently written in Italian, i'm planning to translate it at some point.

Comment: Much as I hate to tout the awful 'Monte Cook's World of Darkness', the magic system in there is very freeform.  Also, the systems from Mage the Ascension and Mage the Awakening are very freeform as well, by design. Of course Ars Magica is already mentioned (though I might quibble over it being the 'most famous' as it has been eclipsed long ago in popularity by both of White Wolf's Mage games. You might also look at the FATE-based magic system from the Dresden Files RPG for a FATE flavor.